# Can nmap run multiple nmap script with multiple arguments in one command?

Tags: nmap

I want to run multiple nmap scripts, each of which takes in one or multiple arguments.

For example, I want to run 3 scripts: sc1, sc2, sc3.

sc1 uses args: sc1.ag1, sc1.ag2, sc1.ag3

sc2 uses args: sc2.ag1, sc2.ag2

sc3 uses args: sc3.ag1

Is it possible to run a command like this?

`nmap --script sc1,sc2,sc3 --script-args=sc1.ag1,sc1.ag2,sc1.ag3,sc2.ag1,sc2.ag2,sc3.ag1 192.168.111.111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is allowed. You should be careful with quoting for your shell, since script args can contain spaces and quote characters.

You may also be interested in the `--script-args-file` option, which allows you to put each script argument on a separate line of a text file. The newline acts the same as the comma (",") in your example.

Script specification is covered in the [online documentation](https://nmap.org/book/nse-usage.html#nse-script-selection).